# is it possible to hide the Input.TextArea border when focus

Tags: html, css

I have a `Input.TextArea` that get user input message, the html look like this:

```jsx
<div className="input-box">
    <Input.TextArea
        id="talkInput"
        rows={1}
        value={inputValue}
        ref={inputRef}
        onChange={handleChatInputChange}
        onKeyPress={handleEnterKey}
        placeholder="input some message，press Enter to send" />
    <Button icon={<SendOutlined style={{ 
        display: 'flex', 
        alignItems: 'center', 
        transform: 'rotate(-45deg)',
        justifyContent: 'center' }}/>}
        loading={loadings}
        onClick={handleSend}
    ></Button>
</div>
```

when I input some content, the `Input.TextArea` will show light blue border. is it possible to make it not show the border? I have tried like this:

```css
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

and also set the border color like this:

```css
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: 0px solid white;
}
```

none of them works. what should I do to make the `Input.TextArea` not show the light blue border?

Comment: Does `Input.TextArea` actually render a `textarea` in the HTML? (What you have looks like JSX to me, but some appropriate tags on the question would be helpful)

Comment: Input.TextArea is antd component, I have replace this component with textarea

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```css
textarea {
  outline: none;
}
```